# Does anyone install CentOS 6.6 or 7 on the HP ProLiant ML10 v2 before?

Tags: linux, centos, web-server, hp, web-hosting

I want to ask that has anyone installed CentOS 6.6 or 7 on HP ProLiant ML10 v2 server yet? B/c on the HP official site didn't mention this server is supported by CentOS but do supported RHEL(Redhat).

Isn't CentOS same as RHEL? if it's same, should be installed and work properly fine, right?

Comment: It should works for CentOS 7, as listed in the below website, good luck!
https://www.linuxnow.com.au/lshp812129-375.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment on that specific server, but it is up to you how closely you want to follow your vendor's supported list. Ask them. Keep in mind they are free to not support you if you don't.

CentOS is a rebuild based on RHEL sources. It is intended to be source compatible and often is binary compatible. So probably, but it isn't the same thing.

Comment: Core CentOS is _binary_ compatible with RHEL.

Answer (score 2):

Yes You can Install it on HP ML10 V2. I have installed CentOS7 it myself and it just work fine.

Note :  Make sure to change the BIOS setting. Press F9 while booting
System Options -> SATA Controller Options -> Embedded SATA Configuration -> Enable SATA AHCI
Support

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

I have done it: here's the instruction http://elektronika.henx.pl/

If it doesn't appear, here's some copy-paste:

2016-03-06 20:45 
HOW-TO: Run CentOS 7 on ProLiant ML10 v2 server with hardware RAID1

Well, the configuration below is listed exactly as it did work for me. Therefore I hosted the text you are reading now on the computer configured following these steps.

1. Enter BIOS (F9) and change SATA mode to b120i smart array raid controller.
2. Boot from Smart Storage Administrator pendrive (remember not to connect the mouse to the SS-USB ports because a mouse is an only navigating device in the program).
   You can download Smart Storage Administrator from official HP site or my server (which will probably be much slower).
3. Create an array from physical drives.
4. Check created logical volume as bootable.
5. Boot from OS-pendrive.
6. Select "Install OS..." and press Esc.
7. Type "linux modprobe.blacklist=ahci init.dd" and hit Enter.
8. Connect the pendrive with the hpvsa driver (the driver must have iso extension, so you can simply rename from *.dd to *.iso).
   You can download the driver here.
9. Type "r" to refresh and hit Enter.
10. Select connected pendrive with drivers.
11. Select the package and hit "c" to continue installing this package, and then hit Enter.
    (Disconnecting the pendrive with drivers might cause an error.)
12. After the driver is installed Type "c" to continue OS installation and hit Enter.
13. When in the OS installation wizard, choose a logical drive to install the OS on.

Good luck!

If case of questions catch me on cyviloo[at]gmail[dot]com

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I installed CentOS 7.2 last year right after question being answered